# How to show all inherited interfaces in GridControl

Tags: devexpress-wpf, devexpress-gridcontrol

We have a `GridControl` and we are assigning the `ItemsSource` to a collection of interface items. The interface used in the collection inherits from another interface, and the problem we are running into is that only items directly defined in the top level interface are being shown in the `GridControl`

Below is a very simplified example of the behavior that we are seeing.

## xaml code defining the `GridControl`

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfThrowaway.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfThrowaway"
        xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <dxg:GridControl x:Name="DataGrid" Background="#363636" Foreground="#FFFFFF" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew">
            <dxg:GridControl.View >
                <dxg:TableView x:Name="TableView" AllowEditing="False" />
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## Concrete item implementation

```cs
    class ConcreteItem : ILevel1
    {
        public string Level1String => "Level 1 string";

        public double Level2Double => 2;
    }
```

## Level 1 interface (type used in the `ItemsSource` collection)

```cs
    interface ILevel1 : ILevel2
    {
        string Level1String { get; }
    }
```

## Level 2 interface

```cs
    interface ILevel2
    {
        double Level2Double { get; }
    }
```

## Code behind to initialize `ItemsSource` in the `MainWindow`

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var concreteItemCollection = new List<ILevel1>();
            for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                concreteItemCollection.Add(new ConcreteItem());
            }
            DataGrid.ItemsSource = concreteItemCollection;
        }
    }
```

## Resulting data grid

[image: Grid Control showing only Level 1 column]

What we want and would expect is for the `GridControl` to show two columns `Level1String` and `Level2Double`, but only the item explicitly defined in the `ILevel1` interface is showing up in the grid.

Is there any workaround for this? How do we get all properties from inherited interfaces to show up as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a hack that works is to cast the top level interface to an object. It will trick the grid control into auto generating the columns based on the concrete implementation, which will get you all of your properties.

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = concreteItemCollection.Select(x => (object)x);
```